# Rutas por defecto de scaffold y controladores

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Tengo una pequeña duda en cuanto a los controladores y las rutas. Estoy desarrollando un sistema de edición de imágenes y lo único que me falta es redirigir a cada ruta, o sea que el usuario va modificando la imagen en cada vista del sistema, primero la vista de subida de imagen, luego pasa directamente a la vista de recorte, luego a la vista de edición, pero cuando llega a la ruta de edición llamada "et", no me esta respondiendo con el método especificado en la ruta, sino que esta respondiendo por el método update del scaffold, y esta ignorando su propio método.

Tengo las siguientes rutas especificadas:

```
 get '/attachments/:id/et', to: 'attachments#et', as: 'et'       #esta ruta redirige a la vista et con la imagen como parametro 

 resources :attachments

 patch '/attachments/:id', to: 'attachments#et_update'
 put '/attachments/:id', to: 'attachments#et_update'
```

A las dos últimas les estoy pidiendo que respondan al método et_update que esta definido en el controlador, pero a la hora de que el sistema haga uso de los métodos, usa el update del scaffold en vez de "et_update".

mi controlador

```
class AttachmentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_attachment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :et, :et_update, :texto, :texto_update]

  # GET /attachments
  # GET /attachments.json
  def index
    @attachments = Attachment.all
  end

  # GET /attachments/1
  # GET /attachments/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /attachments/new
  def new
    @attachment = Attachment.new
  end

  # GET /attachments/1/edit
  def edit

  end

  # POST /attachments
  # POST /attachments.json
  def create
    @attachment = Attachment.new(attachment_params)

    #respond_to do |format|
      if @attachment.save
        if params[:attachment][:image].present?
          render :crop
        else
          format.html { redirect_to @attachment, notice: 'Attachment was successfully created.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @attachment }
        end
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @attachment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    #end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /attachments/1
  # PATCH/PUT /attachments/1.json

def et

end

#edit es el que va a verse
#update recibe los datos para guardarlos, aqui en el scaffold

def et_update

    if params[:base64].present?
                   data =  params[:base64]
                   image_data = Base64.decode64(data['data:image/png;base64,'.length .. -1])
                   File.open("#{Rails.root}/public#{@attachment.image.url.to_s}", 'wb') do |f|
                   f.write image_data
          redirect_to texto_path, notice:"successfully updatesd attachment"

                 end
                  @attachment.image.recreate_versions! if @attachment.image.present?

                  end





end



  def update
    #respond_to do |format|
      if @attachment.update(attachment_params)

          redirect_to et_path, notice:"successfully updated attachment"

          #format.html { redirect_to @attachment, notice: 'Attachment was successfully updated.' }
          #format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @attachment }


      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @attachment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    #end
  end

  # DELETE /attachments/1
  # DELETE /attachments/1.json
  def destroy
    @attachment.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to attachments_url, notice: 'Attachment was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_attachment
      @attachment = Attachment.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def attachment_params
      params.require(:attachment).permit(:image, :name, :crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h, :data, :image_data, :base64, :@ac2, :ac2)
    end
end
```

¿Por qué sucede un comportamiento tan extraño como este?

Comment: En qué parte realizas el redireccionamiento al método `et_update`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema es que seguramente la ruta update está sobreescribiendo la que indicas con et_update.

**Editado**

Otra posibilidad es que la ruta del formulario está definida por defecto `<%= form_for @objeto`, por lo que cuando validas el formulario redirecciona a `edit`. Puedes cambiar este comportamiento de la siguiente forma: `<%= form_for @objeto, :url => {:action => 'et_update'} %>`

De todas maneras puedes ver tus rutas ejecutando en una ventana del servidor local el comando `rake routes` o si no, tratando de mostrar una página no existente `http://localhost:3000/ruta_no_valida`.

Si no utilizas el método update de tu controlador, por qué no colocas el código de actualización de tu modelo en él en vez de crear una nueva acción y complicando tu código?

Comment: Hola @Puce que tal amigo, gracias por tu respuesta. yo tambien estoy pensando eso, que esta sobreescribiendo un metodo al otro, porque cuando coloco uno primero que el otro en las rutas, toma el que esta de primero, ni idea del porque. el metodo update en efecto lo estoy usando, para modificar el nombre de la imagen. y el redireccionamiento lo estoy haciendo desde la ventana index. con un link to         <%= link_to 'Edicion', et_path(attachment) %>
oye y porque sera que me esta tomando sustituyendo el metodo update por mi metodo et_update?

Comment: Seguramente estas usando un formulario con los métodos por defecto, algo del tipo `<%= form_for @objeto do |f| %>`, de esta manera Rails va a redireccionar tu formulario a la accion update del scaffold. 
Lo que puedes hacer es definir la acción a la que redireccionar cuando validas el formulario, con un parámetro `action`. Lo voy a indicar en la respuesta.

Comment: en efecto amigo @Puce estoy haciendo uso de un form_for, seguro que es el que me hace llamar al metodo update, aplique de igual forma :action y de igual forma sigue sustituyendo el update por el et_update o viceversa, dependiendo de cual este de primero en las rutas, no entiendo porque.

Comment: este es mi Form_for                                                                                            
<%= form_for @attachment, action: "et_update" do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <input id="base64" type="text" value="" name="base64"/>

    <div class="actions">

  
    <%= f.submit%>
  </div>
<% end %>

Comment: He hecho una corrección, no es solo :action, sino :url => {:action... Puedes verlo en la respuesta.

Comment: amigo @Puce lo coloque tal cual, pero aun nada, ni idea de porque me sigue utilizando el primer metodo que coloque en las rutas, si coloco el resources de primero, toma el update, o si coloco las rutas del et_update primero, toma estas. vaya anomalia xD me esta volviendo loco no saber resolverlo

Comment: y eso que lo coloque con el url  de esta forma  <%= form_for @attachment, :url => {:action => 'et_update'} do |f| %>

Comment: amigo @Puce estoy casi seguro que me esta mandando al update porque como en la ventana es una edicion de imagenes, yo lo unico que necesito pasar como parametro es esto   <input id="base64" type="text" value="" name="base64"/>
 que es un input con el valor de la imagen codificada a base64, pero no supe como enviar esos datos unicamente,

Comment: asi que lo hice de esta forma <%= form_for @attachment do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <input id="base64" type="text" value="" name="base64"/>
    <%= f.submit%>
  </div>
<% end %>
   tuve que colocar :name porque sino me da un error que param is missing or the value is empty: attachment

Comment: como podria solucionar esto? ya me carca loco ese codigo xD

Comment: Por que no cambias tu form_for a un form_tag y te encargas de generar tu todos los inputs, campos para modificar tu modelo?

Comment: amigo @Puce ya pude solucionar mi problema, lo que me paso es que en las rutas coloque     resources :attachments  
 patch '/attachments/:id', to: 'attachments#et_update'
 put '/attachments/:id', to: 'attachments#et_update'             y el error me daba porque la ruta '/attachments/:id' ya estaba siendo usada por el edit del resources attachment, por eso lo sustituia, debia de colocar una nueva ruta como patch '/attachments/:id/et_update', to: 'attachments#et_update'   y haciendo uso de el url action que me dijiste en comentarios anteriores, pude hacer uso de mi metodo :D

Comment: quiero agradecerte por tu ayuda incondicional, estaba totalmente solo y sin ayuda, de no ser por ti no hubiese dado con la solucion, muchisimas gracias hermano :)